# Xamarin.IOS exception while running ibtool: object cannot be nil (key: family)

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm getting a weird error while trying to build my solution:
Exception while running ibtool: *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: family)

I've googled it but there is no answers to this problem, just questions... Maybe worth mentioning is that I use Visual Studio Community 2015, I got the latest Xcode installed on my Mac and I have a updated iPhone 5s connected to the Mac. The OS on my Mac is El Capitan (10.11.4).

I think this problem mainly comes from my storyboard, at first I got this error when i tried to create a segue for a button between two views. I removed it and it worked as usual, now I got the same error later on in this project and it's not thanks to the segue.

If I exclude my storyboard, I can build the solution without any trouble, but I can't run the app on my iPhone since the storyboard is missing.

Anyone got a clue what the problem might be? Here are the error logs if necessary:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error       Exception while running ibtool: *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: family)
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00000001181c6b41 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x000000011814ee00 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x000000011814d775 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000011815f133 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000011815eeac (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000011815ec66 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000011815d934 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 10  0x00000001181cb205 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 11  0x00000001181ccce7 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 12   -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWhileUsingSourceAsIntermediateDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13   -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWithIntermediateDocumentOfTargetRuntime:alwaysCopy:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x00000001181cc40a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 15  0x00000001181b8b4d (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 16   -[IBStoryboardSceneCompilationGroup compilationResultsForCompilationUnits:options:returningErrors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17   -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileUnitsFromCompilationGroups:filter:options:errors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18   __78-[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileContentsOfStoryboardWithOptions:errors:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19   IBWithAutoInvalidationPool (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20   -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileContentsOfStoryboardWithOptions:errors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21   -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler internalCompileWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x00000001181b8f5e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 23   __57-[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24   -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWithIntermediateDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25   -[IBDocumentCompiler invokeWithIntermediateDocumentOfTargetRuntime:alwaysCopy:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26   -[IBStoryboardDocumentCompiler compileWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27   +[IBDocumentCompiler compileContentsOfDocument:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28   __47-[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager ignoreAutolayoutStatusInvalidationDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30   -[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31   -[IBDocument compileAndWriteToPath:withOptions:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32  0x000000010ceb52da (in ibtoold)
 33  0x000000010ceb10e7 (in ibtoold)
 34  0x000000010ceb36ab (in ibtoold)
 35  0x000000010ceb75c8 (in ibtoold)
 36  0x000000010ceb7c5a (in ibtoold)
 37  0x000000010ceb7b2d (in ibtoold)
 38  0x000000010cea695b (in ibtoold)
 39  0x000000010ceb71c3 (in ibtoold)
 40  0x000000010ceb6274 (in ibtoold)
 41   start (in libdyld.dylib)  FridgeMe.iOS            Build
```

Edit: I removed my second view controller and created a whole new one, this seems to have fixed the problem. Still not sure what was causing the problem, but if anyone knows I would really like to know if this happens agian.

Edit 2: The error came back as soon as I added a button on the other (new) view controller. It also refers to a run time error regarding the button not having a code behind (which I thought was created when you added the button on the storyboard). See the image.
[Seems like the code for the button isn't generated properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7dH9.jpg)

I'm hoping this could be some help for other people who run into this issue. I'm still a bit stuck since I tried to manually copy everything regarding a button (changing it's name of course) from my working view controller to the new one, but I don't seem to get it to work.

I have added following to my ViewControllerCreate.designer.cs:

```
UIKit.UIButton BtnCreateAccount { get; set; }

void ReleaseDesignerOutlets()
{
    if (BtnCreateAccount != null)
    {
        BtnCreateAccount.Dispose();
        BtnCreateAccount = null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks more like an `ibtool` crash than a compilation error. `ibtool` was very unstable a couple of years ago and would randomly crash on a random storyboard (sometimes the build would go through, sometimes not). Does your issue happen every time or does it sometimes build?

Comment: Having the same issue. I get the error when I add a segue in storyboard from one View Controller to another, but when I remove the segue, it builds fine.

Comment: So after removing the segue from the storyboard, and trying to set the transition in code, I still get the error. This time, when I set the Storyboard ID of the View Controller I'm trying to transition to, it won't build. If I leave it blank, it builds fine. However, now I'm altogether stuck without a way to transition to my next controller.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error.

After analyzing the code main.storyboard, I discovered that, in my case, the error jump if a button or other control has something like:
**<fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="HelveticaNeue" pointSize="17" />**

The family  font is the problem, try change to 
<fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17" />  or just delete de line.

Regards,
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following code may be helpful for you.

```
internal class CustomUIView : UIView
{
    internal CustomUIView(IntPtr value) :base(value)

    {

    }
}
```

Example:

```
UIView view = new CustomUIView(IntPtr.Zero);
```

Refer for more information [here](http://monkpal.com/how-give-nil-value-uicolor-xamarinios-xamarin)